# Optimal strategy for this Nim generalisation?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Consider the following game:

There are a number of piles of stones. On each turn a player can remove as many stones he likes (at least 1) from up to $N$ piles (at least 1). It is allowed to remove a different amount of stones from each of the up to $N$ piles. The first player that can't move loses.

For $N=1$ we have the original game of nim with its well known optimal strategy.

For $N \geq$ number of piles the obvious optimal strategy is to remove all the stones.

What is the optimal strategy for $N=2,3,..$?

Extra question: What is the sprague-grundy value for these games?

Comment: "For N=1  we have the original game of nim with its well known optimal strategy." $$ $$ To get started, you can present the optimal strategy for $N=1$. This might help you or others to find an optimal strategy for the case $ N>1$

Comment: That's a good question - I wish I had known the answer last week :). Wait, are you the Ward Beullens who also took part in hackerrank's weekly?

Comment: The Sprague-Grundy theory says that amy position in any impartial game ( pf which this is an example) is equivalent to a single nim-heap, and provides a strategy.  Check it out

Comment: @calculus The well-known strategy is to XOR all pile sizes and make a move that makes the XOR zero (if it is already zero, you lose).

Comment: @MJD Then the real question is: Given heap sizes $n_1, \ldots, n_m$ and $N$, determine $n$ that is equivalent to this game.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, i am!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In my opinion, it is the business of Ward to get started.

Comment: @calculus It's explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory

Comment: Probably one should start by checking what happens in the first non-trivial case, where there are $3$ piles and $N = 2$.

Comment: Must the number of stones you remove from each pile be constant? If there are $3$ piles left and piles have $1$, $2$ and $3$ stones, can you win by removing $3$ stones from each pile, even though there are not that many stones in the first two piles?

Comment: @J.J. You can remove a different amount of stones from each pile.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft if there are $3$ piles and $N=2$ the only losing positions are those in which the 3 piles have the same number of stones. Because you can always move to such a state if this is not already the case.

Comment: Ahh, of course, good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The winning strategy is described under section "Index-k Nim" in
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim.

In short: Instead of doing arithmetic in $Z_2^\infty$, you do it in $Z_{k+1}^\infty$ and choose a move that leaves you with $0$ as a result.

For example, let us consider $N=2$ and three piles of sizes $5,8,10$. The sizes in binary are $101$, $1000$ and $1010$. Their bitwise sum modulo $N+1 = 3$ is $2111$. Remove $3$ stones from the second and $5$ from the third pile to get new pile sizes $101,101,101$, whose mod $3$ sum is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, i posted a follow-up question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917062/what-is-the-sprague-grundy-value-of-these-games